Multiway McNemar-Type Test?
I need a test that would be similar to McNemar, but has e.g. 3 binary outcomes (0,1).  Kappa also comes to mind for something that may be similar like interrator agreement.  However, my hypotheses is more like multiple linear regression for which the alternative is that at least one of the slopes is not zero:
$H_0: \beta_1=\beta_2=\beta_3=0$
$H_a: \beta_j \neq 0 \quad \quad j=1,2,3$
For my 3 binary outcomes, the hypotheses would be:
$H_0: y_1=y_2=y_3=0$
$H_a: y_j =1 \quad \quad j=1,2,3$
However, a problem is that $y_j$ is not an estimator like the mean or a slope, but rather is really $y_{ij}$ for each subject.   Anyhow, the alternative would be that any $y_{ij}$ is one.  I could then invoke contrasts to do this.
I'm also thinking I could also turn this into a straightforward binomial probability problem asking for the probability of at least 1 using
$P(X \geq 1)=\binom{3}{1}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$
and then simply run trials via simulation.

Your second pair of hypotheses is odd to me. Can you put it in words? What are y1 y2 y3 - three separate binary variables or what?

Yes, three binary outcomes from each subject, object.  So they are represented by 3 binary variables, $y_1, y_2, y_3.$

Perhaps you want to compare their three distributions by a single test? If that is so then Cochran's Q test is what you need - it is the repeated measures test for p binary variables [i.e., matched samples] (while McNemar is its specific case and is for 2 variables).

Will look at Cochran's Q.
